# python list append in for loop get only full list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I parse a log file looking for an ERROR tag.
If the word ERROR is present i append the line to a list separated by a ";" to a csv file.
it works, but list is written in file each time an item is adeed
what i want is to write only the full list

```py
def failedfile(directory):
    fcause = []
    for f in os.listdir(directory):
        if f.endswith(".log"):
            filepath = os.path.join(directory,f)
            dfr = os.stat(filepath).st_ctime
            dfhr = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y', time.localtime(dfr))
            with open (filepath, mode="rt", encoding="utf-8") as faillogfile:
                fail = faillogfile.readlines()
                with open(failedfilename, mode='a', newline='') as ff:
                    writer = csv.writer(ff, dialect='excel', delimiter=";")
                    for lines in fail:
                        if "ERROR" in lines:
                            fail2 = ''.join(fail)
                            accessname = re.findall(r'\w{1,4}\-\d{1,3}', fail2)
                            fcause.append(lines)
                            failcause = ';'.join(fcause)
                            print(failcause)
                            market = reglisse(accessname[0])
                            writer.writerow([accessname[0], market, dfhr, failmessage, failcause])
                ff.close
            faillogfile.close
    return (fcause)
```

expected:
`cat failedfilename`

ERROR - first cause of the error;ERROR - second cause of the error;ERROR - operation failed

Actual result:

`cat failedfilename`

ERROR - first cause of the error

ERROR - first cause of the error;ERROR - second cause of the error

ERROR - first cause of the error;ERROR - second cause of the error;ERROR - operation failed

Comment: you should realy use elasticsearch :)

Comment: you are writing inside the innermost loop, and appending to a list at the same time. Just let the full `fcause` list be created, write the output only at the end. (Or some other alternatives, but the point is, it's showing you the output because *you* asked it to write it that way.)

Comment: thanks for your answers. now it works all fine